# ASP.NET Core and SignalR Documentation

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, signalr

Where Can I find full documentation for the SignalR?
And how can I solve my problem?
For example - I don't know how is work this method

`app.UseEndpoints(endpoint => endpoint.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chat"));`

How can I call this method like another way, not a lambda.

Comment: The document of SignalR is here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?tabs=visual-studio-code&view=aspnetcore-3.1  and you really should google it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid a lambda, simply write a function with the same content, and put the name of the function here.

In your case, to avoid lambda for:

```cs
app.UseEndpoints(endpoint => endpoint.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chat"));
```

Change it to

```cs
// Start up.cs begin
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;

// Put this somewhere in your StartUp class
public void OnEndpointConfigure(IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoint)
{
    endpoint.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chat");
}

app.UseEndpoints(OnEndpointConfigure);
```